# Dragged Element Not Available on UIKit Sortable on Stop (v2.27.1)

Tags: javascript, event-handling, uikit, dom-events, jquery-ui-sortable

```
this.$container.find('[data-uk-sortable]').on('stop.uk.sortable', function(e, el, type){
    //type is null here
}

this.$container.on('stop.uk.sortable', '[data-uk-sortable]', function(e, el, type){
    //type is null here
}
```

Documentation on UIKit website says that it should be available and I also found many example online that shows that it's supposed to be available, but it's not.

https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/sortable.html

Is there another way to get the element that is dragged?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `el.drag["0"]`, which gives me the `div` I am dragging.